# How to compare query performance with & without indexes on a table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, time, indexing

I am learning about indexes, I know how they work, but I can't see the difference in numbers which would help me A LOT. I am asking for tips & tricks how to check most important factors :)

Besides, I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query execution plans would be a valuable resource to look at, to see how the queries are performing. Additionally, you could use the following commands in SSMS to capture some metrics of the query execution:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

This will give you details of time taken and IO operations performed for each statement in your batch